# ViewPager: After activity recreated, one Fragments stays empty

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have a ViewPager with two Fragments in it. When both are loaded,

- I change the language, or the Dark Mode of the app,
- So the underlying Activity is recreated (I think this is what triggers the bug),
- Then I navigate back to the viewpager,
- Then one of the two fragments (always the first one) is just empty. It doesn't load, it  doesn't respond to clicks, it doesn't do anything. While the other one is recreated and works like a charm.

---

Fragment that contains the ViewPager:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mBinding = MyFragmentBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
    View view = mBinding.getRoot();

    viewPager = mBinding.pageTabber;

    pageAdapter = new MyPageAdapter(getActivity(), getActivity(), this);
    viewPager.setAdapter(pageAdapter);

    new TabLayoutMediator(mBinding.tabLayout, viewPager,
            new TabLayoutMediator.TabConfigurationStrategy() {
                @Override
                public void onConfigureTab(@NonNull TabLayout.Tab tab, int position) {
                    if (getContext() == null) {
                        return;
                    }
                    switch (position) {
                        case 0:
                            tab.setText(...);
                            break;

                        case 1:
                            tab.setText(...);
                            break;

                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
    ).attach();

    viewPager.registerOnPageChangeCallback(new ViewPager2.OnPageChangeCallback() {
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {}
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {}

        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            // ...
        }
    });
}
```

MyPageAdapter:

```
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity;
import androidx.viewpager2.adapter.FragmentStateAdapter;

public class MyPageAdapter extends FragmentStateAdapter {

    private int nr = -1;
    private Context context;

    private static final int FRAGMENT_COUNT = 2;

    public MyPageAdapter(@NonNull FragmentActivity fm, Context context) {
        super(fm);
        this.context = context;
    }

    public MyPageAdapter(@NonNull FragmentActivity fm, int nr, Context context) {
        super(fm);
        this.nr = nr;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return super.getItemId(position);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Fragment createFragment(int position) {
        if (position == 0) {
            return new Fragment1();

        } else {
            return new Fragment2();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return FRAGMENT_COUNT;
    }
}
```

I have added logs to the lifecycles of the Fragments in order to understand it. `WrappingFragments` is the Fragment that contains the ViewPager.

```
// navigating to the fragment that contains the ViewPager
2022-07-03 12:34:02.502 23112-23112/Log: WrappingFragment: onAttach
2022-07-03 12:34:02.502 23112-23112/Log: WrappingFragment: onCreateView
2022-07-03 12:34:02.624 23112-23112/Log: WrappingFragment: onResume
2022-07-03 12:34:02.675 23112-23112/Log: Fragment1: onAttach
2022-07-03 12:34:02.676 23112-23112/Log: Fragment1: onCreateView
2022-07-03 12:34:02.737 23112-23112/Log: Fragment1: onResume


// in the ViewPager: navigating to Fragment2
2022-07-03 12:34:32.114 23112-23112/Log: Fragment2: onAttach
2022-07-03 12:34:32.114 23112-23112/Log: Fragment2: onCreateView
2022-07-03 12:34:32.416 23112-23112/Log: Fragment1: onPause
2022-07-03 12:34:32.416 23112-23112/Log: Fragment2: onResume


// navigating to a different activity in order to change the dark mode setting
2022-07-03 12:34:53.209 23112-23112/Log: WrappingFragment: onPause
2022-07-03 12:34:54.594 23112-23112/Log: Fragment2: onPause
2022-07-03 12:34:55.368 23112-23112/Log: WrappingFragment: onStop
2022-07-03 12:34:55.368 23112-23112/Log: Fragment1: onStop
2022-07-03 12:34:55.368 23112-23112/Log: Fragment2: onStop


// Changing the dark mode setting
2022-07-03 12:35:09.957 23112-23112/Log: WrappingFragment: onDestroyView
2022-07-03 12:35:09.957 23112-23112/Log: WrappingFragment: onDestroy
2022-07-03 12:35:09.957 23112-23112/Log: WrappingFragment: onDetach
2022-07-03 12:35:09.958 23112-23112/Log: Fragment1: onDestroyView
2022-07-03 12:35:09.958 23112-23112/Log: Fragment1: onDestroy
2022-07-03 12:35:09.959 23112-23112/Log: Fragment1: onDetach
2022-07-03 12:35:09.959 23112-23112/Log: Fragment2: onCreateView
2022-07-03 12:35:09.959 23112-23112/Log: Fragment2: onCreateView
2022-07-03 12:35:09.960 23112-23112/Log: Fragment2: onDetach
2022-07-03 12:35:09.987 23112-23112/Log: WrappingFragment: onAttach
2022-07-03 12:35:09.987 23112-23112/Log: Fragment1: onAttach
2022-07-03 12:35:09.988 23112-23112/Log: Fragment2: onAttach
2022-07-03 12:35:10.165 23112-23112/Log: WrappingFragment: onCreateView
2022-07-03 12:35:10.226 23112-23112/Log: Fragment1: onCreateView
2022-07-03 12:35:10.246 23112-23112/Log: Fragment2: onCreateView
2022-07-03 12:35:10.360 23112-23112/Log: Fragment2: onResume
2022-07-03 12:35:10.378 23112-23112/Log: Fragment2: onPause
2022-07-03 12:35:10.389 23112-23112/Log: WrappingFragment: onStop
2022-07-03 12:35:10.389 23112-23112/Log: Fragment1: onStop
2022-07-03 12:35:10.390 23112-23112/Log: Fragment2: onStop


// navigating back to the other activity (where all the fragments are in)
2022-07-03 12:50:22.049 23112-23112/Log: Fragment2: onResume
2022-07-03 12:50:22.087 23112-23112/Log: WrappingFragment: onStop
2022-07-03 12:50:22.087 23112-23112/Log: WrappingFragment: onDestroyView
2022-07-03 12:50:22.088 23112-23112/Log: WrappingFragment: onDestroy
2022-07-03 12:50:22.088 23112-23112/Log: WrappingFragment: onDetach


// navigating to the Fragment that contains the ViewPager (the viewpager starts in fragment2 as when I navigated out of this, we were in fragment2)
2022-07-03 12:50:37.822 23112-23112/Log: WrappingFragment: onAttach
2022-07-03 12:50:37.822 23112-23112/Log: WrappingFragment: onCreateView
2022-07-03 12:50:37.880 23112-23112/Log: WrappingFragment: onResume


// in the ViewPager going to Fragment1
2022-07-03 12:50:47.322 23112-23112/Log: Fragment2: onPause
2022-07-03 12:50:47.323 23112-23112/Log: Fragment1: onResume
```

But I just cannot find an error.

Comment: As per the documentation, `createFragment` should always return a new instance of a Fragment where its state will be restored if it was lost before. Check this: https://developer.android.com/training/animation/vp2-migration#adapter-methods

Comment: Thanks, I edited the code and update the question. Unfortunately it doesn't solve the problem.